# How to check the datatype of an ndarray in C

Tags: c, numpy

Could anyone tell me how to check the data type of an `ndarray` that has been passed to C code?

In the concrete example I would like to call a different function if the datatype of the array is `float32` or `double/float64`. So something like

```
if( Dtype(MyArray) == NPY_FLOAT )
{
   DoSomething_float( MyArray );
}
else
{
   DoSomething_double( MyArray );
}
```

I already found

```
PyTypeNum_ISFLOAT(num)
PyDataType_ISFLOAT(descr)
PyArray_ISFLOAT(obj)
```

In the numpy C API, but I don't understand how to use those. I've already tried to find an instructive example but have found none.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you are almost there, as you are looking for `PyArray_TYPE`:

```
int typ=PyArray_TYPE(MyArray);

switch(typ) {
case NPY_FLOAT:
    DoSomething_single(MyArray);
    break;
case NPY_DOUBLE:
    DoSomething_double(MyArray);
    break;
default:
    error("unknown type %d of MyArray\n", typ);
}
```

Comment: Oh, that easy, sorry for not finding that myself, I was stuck on the wrong commands.
Thank you very much

Comment: For future ref, the doc for this macro is [located here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#c.PyArray_TYPE).

Answer (score 4):

The long, convoluted way of doing this, if you are dealing with a `PyArrayObject* arr`, would be to check `arr->descr->type` or `arr->descr->type_num`which holds:

> `char PyArray_Descr.type`
>   A traditional character code indicating the data type
>
> `int PyArray_Descr.type_num` A number that uniquely identifies the data
>   type. For new data-types, this number is assigned when the data-type
>   is registered

As @umlauete answer points out, there are cleaner ways of incorporating that into your code, but it is always a good thing to know what's in your `PyArrayObject` and `PyArray_Descr`structs. And always "read [the docs](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.types-and-structures.html), Luke!"

Comment: Thanks for the insight, I'm just slowly making my way into the whole numpy C business so some docs still seem cryptic to me. So your comment is very much appriciated, thanks